# STM32F407 USART Interrupt config

Tags: stm32, uart

Is it possible to Enable multiple USART Interrupts simultaneously by CMSIS **USART_ITConfig** function? I mean is it correct to utilize **USART_ITConfig** like this :

```
USART_ITConfig(USART1,USART_IT_TXE|USART_IT_RXNE,ENABLE)
```

or i should call **USART_ITConfig** function for each interrupt to enable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read The Fine Manual

> USART_IT,: specifies the USART interrupt sources to be enabled or disabled. This parameter can be **one of the following values**:
>
> - USART_IT_CTS: CTS change interrupt
> - USART_IT_LBD: LIN Break detection interrupt
> - USART_IT_TXE: Transmit Data Register empty interrupt
> - USART_IT_TC: Transmission complete interrupt
> - USART_IT_RXNE: Receive Data register not empty interrupt
> - USART_IT_IDLE: Idle line detection interrupt
> - USART_IT_PE: Parity Error interrupt
> - USART_IT_ERR: Error interrupt(Frame error, noise error, overrun error)

So don't try any combinations. Looking at the library source, it actually checks and rejects any value not in the list, if `USE_FULL_ASSERT` is enabled.

If you'd like to have short, fast, and easy to understand code, just write

```
USART1->CR1 |= USART_CR1_RXNEIE | USART_CR1_TXEIE;
```